# Ubuntu 14.04 hangs intermittently under Hyper-V

Tags: ubuntu, freeze, hyper-v

I have Ubuntu Server 14.04.1 LTS running in a Hyper-V virtual machine on a Windows 2012 R2 host.

After running for some time, the Ubuntu server seems to freeze up (at least partially).  A website it's hosting under nginx stops working.  I can connect via Putty and enter my username and password, but then the session immediately hangs:

[image: Login hangs]

The same thing happens when I try to log in from the console (making it difficult to check logs / troubleshoot).  However I do notice output like this sitting in the console window:

[image: Console window]

If there is a local or remote console session that is already logged in, I can still interact with it.  However any attempt to write to the disk freezes the session.

I managed to snag a [dmesg dump](http://pastebin.com/FfS8c7uD) and recent content of [kernel.log](http://pastebin.com/jwR1VMqq).  And here's an earlier, partial dmesg [screencap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KsXV.png) in case it is of use.

I believe the issue may be related to the disk I/O stack:

```
[16209.927138] hv_storvsc vmbus_0_13: cmd 0x35 scsi status 0x2 srb status 0x82
[16209.927142] hv_storvsc vmbus_0_13: stor pkt ffff88003b203100 autosense data valid - len 18
[16209.927144] storvsc: Sense Key : Unit Attention [current]
[16209.927146] storvsc: Add. Sense: Changed operating definition
[16209.927151] sd 0:0:0:0: Warning! Received an indication that the operating parameters on this target have changed. The Linux SCSI layer does not automatically adjust these parameters.
[45841.680551] INFO: task rs:main Q:Reg:882 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[45841.680580]       Not tainted 3.13.0-32-generic #57-Ubuntu
[45841.680596] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
```

The install is fairly fresh and default settings were accepted for pretty much everything.  The VM is using Hyper-V's "generation 2" guest architecture, with secure boot disabled.

My symptoms seem similar to those reported [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1506343), [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/68bf3ab9-e42e-40cc-a216-e847b97124d2/io-errro-on-disk-in-virtual-centos-disk-remounted-read-only?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows) and [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1797737), but those threads are a few years old and refer to older versions of guest & host.

The server still responds to pings.  Also note we saw the freezing behavior before nginx was installed.

I don't think it's a resource issue.  The VM has 1GB of RAM and plenty of disk space.  Here's what things look like before it freezes:

```
  System information as of Sun Aug  3 16:03:30 EDT 2014

  System load:  0.08              Processes:           231
  Usage of /:   3.6% of 96.59GB   Users logged in:     1
  Memory usage: 29%               IP address for eth0: 172.22.0.26
  Swap usage:   0%
```

I'm looking for:

1. Tips on how to *efficiently* troubleshoot this
2. Instructions on how to turn off any sort of disk-related features (e.g. power saving) that came out of the box in my Ubuntu install.
3. A recommendation on where to find a Linux + Hyper-V genius we can hire remotely to help sort this out (and maybe other occasional Linux work)

Answer (score 0):

I found an info in the French Ubuntu forums from other user who has Ubuntu freezes: It may be caused by "dynamic tick".

Their solution:

```
cd /etc/default
sudo vi grub
```

add `nohz=true` in parameters of the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`. Then do a

```
sudo grub-update
```

Comment: Hi Dominique, I do not have Dynamic Memory enabled, so it's not likely that is causing the issue.

Comment: Please only post answers if you have a definitive solution. Also take care of formatting your posts properly, and note that this is not a forum, so you should always edit your existing post rather than posting another one.

Comment: ok I do not want to bore anyone, I'll get my solution elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I think I also have this problem – have you found this:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1470250